# How to check if a variable is null in php?

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

I have the following function:

```
function twetting($value, $msg, $img, $link).
```

Sometimes the variable $img will bring a link to an image, but sometimes it won't I am tryng to write a condition to check when the img has some content and when it does not. I have the following:

```
if(is_null($img)){

        $params = array(
        'status' => $msg." ".$link);
    $reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);

    }

else{

$params = array(
        'status' => $msg." ".$link,
        'media[]' => $img
        );
    $reply = $cb->statuses_updateWithMedia($params);
}
```

I have also tried empty and isset, but none of them work. Can anyone help me pelase??

Comment: @JohnConde if I use is_null it does not work at all.

Comment: This would work if you actually pass in null for $img when no image was clicked, otherwise you might actually just be passing in an empty string which is different.

Comment: perhaps you could try loading the contents using `file_get_contents($img);`

Comment: `if(VARIABLE === NULL)` possibly?

Comment: Use `var_dump()` to get the actual value and **STOP GUESSING**

Comment: @Lochemage in that case of an string I should use empty right?

Comment: try using `if (empty($img))` instead, it will account for null or empty string

Comment: @Lochemage I have tried empty before, but let me double check one more time

Answer (score 0):

You might use a default value on your function declaration for the image value:

- `function twetting($value, $msg, $img = '', $link)`

and then compare against that:

- `if($img === '') { } else { }`
- `if($img !== '') { } else { }`

Some reminders:

- isset() = check if set and not null
- empty(), !empty() = check if empty or not
- is_null() = check if var is null

here you go:

```
function twetting($value, $msg, $img = '', $link) {
....
   $params = array();
   $params['status'] = $msg." ".$link;

    if($img !== '' && is_string($img)) {
        $params['media[]'] = $img;
        $reply = $cb->statuses_updateWithMedia($params);
    } else {
        $reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);
    }
}
```

Comment: The values come from a database, sometimes the database returns an empty string and sometimes the variable contains an string which in this case is a link

Comment: I think this fits: `if($img !== '') { it's a string, here a link } else { it's empty }`. Throw a string check in there, to be on the safe side..depends on your db.

Comment: I think the problem comes from the database. I have checked my function independently testing one condition first and then after, and it works. However, if I have two rows, one with $img empty and the other one with a string, it does not work.

Comment: i've added a piece of example code. i would suggest to ignore the db. test your php function independently with different values: like "1", "abc", "" and a link.

Answer (score 0):

$img !== NULL 
strleng($img)>0
should help

Answer (score 0):

try

if(!empty($img))
{

this means it's not empty

}else
{

this means it is empty.

}